# normal and compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

‎I ‎have ‎recently  started normal operations, but I  face with problems in this ‎regard.‎‎ please guide ‎me.‎

**a: ‎let‎ ‎$  T ‎\in K ( H ) $‎ ‎be‎    ‎normal, ‎show that ‎‎‎$‎T ‎\geq 0 ‎‎‎‎‎$ ‎if ‎only ‎if ‎all eigenvalues( Special value)  of the operator is equal to zero..‎‎**

**b:‎‎‎let‎ ‎$  T ‎\in K ( H ) $‎ ‎be‎ ‎$ T ‎\geq ‎0‎ $‎, ‎prove ‎that‎ There ‎is a‎ ‎‎ positive and unique compact actuator ‎$  ‎A‎$‎ so ‎that‎ ‎$ ‎A‎^{2} =‎ ‎T‎. $‎**

Comment: What's an actuator?

Comment: @Jose27: obviously, "operator".